# Is it safe to reference a value in unordered_map

Tags: c++

For example:

```
#include <unordered_map>

class A{};
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, A> map {{0,{}},{1, {}},{2, {}}};

int main() {
  A& a1 = map[1];
  // some insert and remove operations ( key 1 never removed)
  // ....
}
```

Is it safe to still use `a1` to reference the value which key is "1", after a lot of insert operations?

In other word:
since std::vector will move elements if the capacity changed, a reference of it's element is not guarantee to be valid. Is this fact also fits for `unordered_map`?

Comment: Isn't references to elements of `std::vector` safe even if its location in the memory changes?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's similar to the [iterator invalidation rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#Iterator_invalidation)

Comment: @김선달 "reference to a vector" and "reference to an element in a vector" are not the same .

Comment: Or not. Apparently I'm wrong about that. See [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62254015/10957435).

Comment: @ravenisadesk Oh I made a typo. I mean its elements

Comment: Look at the operations you want to perform on the data structure and see if any of them invalidate references.

Comment: @김선달 you can try it, after the capacity changed, your reference to an element will be invalid. C++ do not have features like Java which will redirection a pointer (a reference in C++ term)

Comment: @ravenisadesk Hmm I didn't know that. +1 knowledge! thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. From the standard:

> 22.2.7 Unordered associative containers [unord.req]
>
> The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of
>   references to container elements, but may invalidate all iterators to
>   the container. The erase members shall invalidate only iterators and
>   references to the erased elements, and preserve the relative order of
>   the elements that are not erased.

References are safe, but iterators are not!

Comment: Hi Sam, I'm curious: how can implementations actually guarantee that? If I'm a hash table and I need to grow, I might have to relocate all of the underlying array to a different memory location. Any idea?

Comment: An unordered container is typically a hash table of pointers and the values in the container are, therefore unaffected by the remapping.

Comment: So when I do `some_unordered_map.insert(some_key, some_value)`, `some_value` is copied to some array X somewhere - and that array will always stay where it was first allocated. And a pointer to that location is set in a different array Y, which may indeed resize and relocate over time. And when I do `some_unordered_map.find(some_key)`, the lookup is performed on the array Y, and will always return a pointer to the same location in array X. And that's why keeping this pointer (or reference) around is valid. Am I roughly correct?

Comment: There's nothing that requires that `some_value` be copied to an `array`. In common implementations of hashing containers, values in the container are kept in individual linked lists, with array buckets serving as hash buckets; quite analogus to `std::vector<std::list<T>>`. In any case, `unordered_map` is a template. Which means that you will find 100% of the code of your particular C++ compiler's `unordered_map` implementation in its header files. If you are interest to understand how it works, you can simply read it yourself, from your compiler's headers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a "less authoritative" source, but easier to read:

*References to elements in the unordered_map container remain valid in
all cases, even after a rehash*

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/

Answer (score 2):

> after a lot of insert operations?

If you meant [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) or [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace), then it's fine.

(emphasis mine)

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. **References are not invalidated**. Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`. If the insertion is successful, pointers and references to the element obtained while it is held in the node handle are invalidated, and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was extracted become valid. (since C++17)